# A basic C++ recursion question I can't wrap my head around

Tags: c++, recursion

I am learning the basics of CPP programming. I came across this basic recursion question which I'm unable to understand. The output is 1 2 3 4 5 but I don't understand why.

At the first iteration (f(5)), we get into the if condition and call f(5-1). Won't calling f(5-1) here (before cout) take us back to the f(int n) function and skip printing anything at all.
Even if we do go to cout after f(5-1), won't cout display 5 instead of 1 for the first iteration? Here is the code. Thank you!

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void f(int n)
    {
      if (n > 0)
      {
        f(n - 1);
        cout << n << " ";
      }
    }
    int main()
    {
      f(5);
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Well, that is a *very* basic recursion question. Remember a function can be called multiple times. Walk through it linearly. `f(5)` will call `f(4)`, which will...

Comment: it's because the function is called again before the current number is printed, so it will call f(4) then f(3) then f(2) then f(1) then f(0) and since f(0) doesn't enter if statement and doesn't call anything, it goes back to f(1) then prints the number 1...and so on

Comment: First think about what `f(0)` does. Then think about `f(1)`.

Comment: You could step through the code 1 line at a time in a debugger looking at the variables and flow at each step. Maybe start with `f(3);` instead of `f(5);`

Comment: Use a debugger and set a conditional breakpoint for `n == 0` and inspect the call stack (and possibly continue the execution step by step...

Comment: The recursive call only executes if the `if` statement is entered. When the `if` statement doesn't execute and the function returns, the frame that made the recursive call continues on to the next statement.

Comment: Thank you all for taking out time to help me. I'll try each one of your suggestions and reply back on how it goes.